# Maven Link to an External Project Directory

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I need to use base code from a different project. The project folders are laid out as this:

```
 cs4500-sinanspd-maxlever
 |
  ------ 2
 |
  ------ 3
```

so 2 & 3 are subdirectories under the main folder and they are 2 SEPARATE projects. I successfully linked module 2 to module 3 in IntelliJ.

[image]

And I can use it. IntelliJ finds all the classes in the source folder

[image]

However when I try to compile the project 3 I get the following **ERROR**:

```
  java: package schema does not exist
```

Now I did some research but the solutions I found did not work:

[Maven compile: package does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17250741/maven-compile-package-does-not-exist)

[Maven: best way of linking custom external JAR to my project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5692256/maven-best-way-of-linking-custom-external-jar-to-my-project)

I can not use mvn install:install-file because this is a module rather than a jar

The pom file for project 3:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>3</groupId>
<artifactId>3</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>2</groupId>
        <artifactId>2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
 </project>
```

and the iml file  shows the library path set successfully :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module    org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsManager.isMavenModule="true"   type="JAVA_MODULE" version="4">
  <component name="NewModuleRootManager" LANGUAGE_LEVEL="JDK_1_8" inherit- compiler-output="false">
    <output url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/target/classes" />
    <output-test url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/target/test-classes" />
<content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$">
  <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/java" isTestSource="false" />
  <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/resources" type="java-resource" />
  <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/test/java" isTestSource="true" />
  <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/target" />
</content>
<orderEntry type="inheritedJdk" />
<orderEntry type="sourceFolder" forTests="false" />
<orderEntry type="module-library">
  <library>
    <CLASSES>
      <root url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/../2" />
    </CLASSES>
    <JAVADOC />
    <SOURCES>
      <root url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/../2/src/main/java" />
    </SOURCES>
  </library>
</orderEntry>
<orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: 2:2:1.0-SNAPSHOT" level="project" />
 </component>
</module>
```

Any help is appreciated. If any other document/information is needed, please drop a comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who have similar issues, 
  The solution for me was to extract both projects into executable jars and 
link them in parallel using

```
mvn install:install-file
```

before compiling the projects. Also specified both jars in the pom file under dependencies.

After this if you try to compile the projects maven puts everything in order for you