# Error during Maven Build when generating WSDL client: " error: package com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.encoding does not exist"

Tags: java, web-services, maven, wsdl

I am upgrading a maven (3.3.9) project with multiple modules from java 1.6 to 1.7 and I am seeing the following errors upon regeneration of the WSDL client (jax-RPC).

When I generated the WSDL client via the Web Services --> Generate Client tool, it creates a referenced library of the thin client "com.ibm.ws.webservices.thinclient_8.5.0.jar" where all these dependencies lie. None of my generated classes have red compilation errors (before compile, it can find all these dependencies in the same package...)

...but upon maven build, it cannot seem to find these packages. My webserver is pointing towards 1.7, my IDE (which is RSA..) is 1.7. Pom dependencies are 1.7, deleted the previous generated client and regenerated via 1.7. What gives?

Errors:

```
error:  package com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.encoding.ser  does    not exist
error:  package com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.description   does    not exist
error:  package com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.encoding  does    not exist
error:  package com.ibm.ws.webservices.multiprotocol    does    not exist
```

[Pic 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSJOb.png)

Note that the thin client is in the build path. I've attempted to delete/re-add it to the build path (refresh...regenerated client......etc) to no avail

[Pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y473h.png)

Note that my classes contain no red. It seems to find the path here, but not in maven.

Comment: Did you try doing a mvn clean install?

Comment: Yep yep -- that's how I run it every time. The clean itself is successful, but the clean install fails.[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 17.672s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu May 04 10:16:02 CDT 2017
[INFO] Final Memory: 12M/21M

Comment: are you pointing to the correct repository `<localRepository>${user.home}/.m2/repository</localRepository>` and also are the credentials correctly entered in your `settings.xml` file?

Comment: Yep yep -- it all builds proper previous to the upgrade to 1.7. I brought it in and built this, successfully, with the repository pulls occurring proper. It's not error'ing on downloading dependencies, it's flat out saying they don't exist on a maven build

Comment: May be this can help you out: (Not exact issue but kinda pointer) http://stackoverflow.com/a/17251659/1004631

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see in the image that client is added in classpath through build path option. This is not right.

If you want the client to get referred in your classpath in maven build, you need to first publish that as a maven dependency and then add that dependency in pom.

Comment: Do you know the dependency by chance? I attempted to add the WAS 8.5 server as a dependency, but that seems to create further errors<dependency>
      <groupId>com.ibm.tools.target</groupId>
      <artifactId>was</artifactId>
      <version>8.5.5</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

Comment: com.ibm.ws.webservices.thinclient_8.5.0 is the dependency which you need and which you generate from wsdl. So, first generate the thin client from wsdl, then install that thin client jar in local maven repo using install:install-file goal and then use that in your pom.